# How to make traefik automatically assign to one frontend docker backends from the same image?

Tags: docker, traefik

I am starting to convert all my `systemd-nspawn` containers to a `docker` and `traefik` solution and I managed to have a frontend created automatically once a `docker` container (the backend) is started.

**I would like to have several containers started from the same docker image (each with an auto-created name) to be attached to a frontend which name I would set.** Is such a setup possible?

In other words, today once I run

```
# docker run myimage
# docker run myimage
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5b4af3466ba6        wazaa               "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    5000/tcp            cranky_montalcini
59b1be83bf98        wazaa               "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    5000/tcp            inspiring_goldwasser
```

I get two containers (`cranky-montalcini` and `inspiring-goldwasser` per the screenshot below and `docker ps` output above) which have two frontends assigned. I, on the other hand, would like to have them assigned to a single `myfrontend.example.com` which would somehow recognize that containers spawned from `myimage` are for him.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, so my apologies if this answer doesn't quite hit the mark. You should only have one "frontend" (which is your traefik container). Traefik maps new containers to backends based on their name.  If you want two containers with different names to be considered as part of the same backend (so that requests directed to that backend will round-robin between them), you can set the `traefik.backend` label.  For example, this would make the following two containers members of the `foo` backend:

```
docker run --label traefik.backend=foo some_image
docker run --label traefik.backend=foo another_image
```

This assumes, of course, that you have also configured an appropriate `traefik.frontend.rule` that would direct traffic to this particular backend.

See https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/ for additional information.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with a screenshot showing the two "frontends" I was talking about. My goal would be to have one frontend on the left, connected to the two backends on the right. Do I understand correctly that with the `--label` you provided in your answer I would have `foo.example.com` generated and connected to these two backends? Thanks for the pointer to the docs, this is the one I used to build my configuration